# GAE query working for unit testing but not local testing

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine

My unit testing working fine for this query, but when i run my app in local it doesn't find the column seller.

```
String statement = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " "
+ "INNER JOIN " + DbSeller.TABLE_NAME + " seller ON video.seller = seller.id "
+ "WHERE video.name LIKE ?";        
//create statement
PreparedStatement stmt = DataBase.getInstance().prepareStatement(statement);        
//set data
stmt.setString(1, "%" + s + "%");
//send query
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
//the result
while(rs.next()) {          
  Video v = new Video();
  System.out.println("test === " + rs.getInt("seller.id")); // <---- EXCEPTION (Column not found!!!!)
  set(rs, v);           
  listVideo.add(v);         
}   
stmt.close();
```

And if i do this instead, it is fine: (Just for the test i don't want ending up writing column by column which info i need)

```
String statement = "SELECT video.*, seller.id as seller_id FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " "
+ "INNER JOIN " + DbSeller.TABLE_NAME + " seller ON video.seller = seller.id "
+ "WHERE video.name LIKE ?";        
//create statement
PreparedStatement stmt = DataBase.getInstance().prepareStatement(statement);        
//set data
stmt.setString(1, "%" + s + "%");
//send query
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
//the result
while(rs.next()) {          
  Video v = new Video();
  System.out.println("test === " + rs.getInt("seller_id")); // <---- NO EXCEPTION
  set(rs, v);           
  listVideo.add(v);         
}   
stmt.close();
```

Note: My app is running on the same offline database in MySQL, so the only difference is that i run this query through my app instead of the unit testing.

Comment: What is the exception being thrown?

Comment: column not found (seller.id)

Comment: Are all of the column names unique across both `video` and `seller`, i.e. are you sure that there are not two columns called `id`. If there are shared column names then you cannot use `select *`, and `select *` should be avoided as far as possible

Comment: yes id is shared, but i even try to put video.*, seller.* in the select clause with the same result

Comment: Specifying a qualifier prefix is not the same as providing an alias. The columns will still have the same name `id` in the result set. And once the query has finished executing the only the result set remains, you no longer have scope to use the qualifier prefix. So you can't refer to a specific column if its name is not unique within the result set.

Comment: But this is giving an Alias ***INNER JOIN " + DbSeller.TABLE_NAME + " seller*** to my table. Or do you have any suggestion to make the 1st query work? Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Column names `seller_id` (underscore) and `seller.id` (dot) look different to me

Comment: just for the testing i want the first one to work, look at comment "Exception"